# Create model instances with foreign key set to CharField

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm using Django 1.8 and try to create a new instance of Tweet like this:

```
user_instance = User.objects.get(screen_name="KalleAnka") # exists
t = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(from_user_id=user_instance)
t.text = "hullabaloo my friend!"
t.to_user = "KajsaAnka"
t.save()
```

My models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    token_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Tweet(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey('User', to_field="screen_name")
    to_user = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'from_user_id' into field. Choices  are: from_user, id, text, to_user
```

If I instead create the new instance of tweet using this (_id removed):

```
t = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(from_user=user_instance)
```

It complains that there is no such column in the database:

```
OperationalError: no such column: tweets_tweet.from_user
```

If I instead use double underscore (__id)

```
t = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(from_user__id=user_instance)
```

I get the following error:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'id' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

I also tried putting .id on the user_instance when creating the new Tweet instance, with no luck (and ran migrations):

I've read at least 10 different similar questions and of course [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), but I can't figure out why it doesn't work like this.

SOLUTION: I had to unpack the value "created" when creating the Tweet instance:

```
t, **created** = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(from_user_id=user_instance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need:

```
user = "KalleAnka" # exist as instance if User
t, created = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(from_user=user)
t.text = "hullabaloo my friend!"
t.to_user = "KajsaAnka"
t.save()
```

You always pass an instance of the model for a ForeignKey field when executing an ORM call.

I made a sample project at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6pb4rbz0iyol21/tweets_app.zip?dl=0

I tweaked your model code slightly not to collide with Django's User model, here are the results I get:

```
>>> from tweets.models import Tweet, TwitterUser
>>> twitter_user = TwitterUser.objects.get(screen_name='KalleAnka')
>>> t, created = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(from_user=twitter_user)
>>> t.text = "hullabaloo my friend!"
>>> t.to_user = "KajsaAnka"
>>> t.save()
>>> t
<Tweet: Tweet object>
>>> t.from_user
<TwitterUser: TwitterUser object>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I should get an instance of the user "KalleAnka" like so:  `user_instance = User.objects.get(screen_name="KalleAnka")` and pass in to `t = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(from_user=user)`But then I get the error message `OperationalError: no such column: tweets_tweet.from_user
`

Comment: @mattiasostmar and allow null in your Tweet fields.

Comment: @mattiasostmar I don't understand your question. `.save()` always returns an instance of the type it creates. `t` in this case will be a `Tweet` instance. `.get_or_create()` returns a double; the object and whether or not it was created

Comment: Am I using .get_or_create incorrectly, do you mean? I edited my question to include the actual code I use to get back an instance of the model User with the name "KalleAnka". I still get an error.

Comment: Are you missing a migration?

Comment: @Brandon No, I ran it again to be sure.

Comment: The field error you're getting is because the ForeignKey is linked to the `screen_name` of the `User` model.

Comment: @brandon I removed the to_field="screen_name" in model.py and ran a migration. I then tried the three different from_user, from_user_id and from_user__id versions again with no different results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96733/discussion-between-brandon-and-mattiasostmar).